# JavaFX do not load an image in an imageview

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I try to add a splash screen to my JavaFX application. The frame for the splash screen shown, but the image inside do not load. I can see with the debugger, set the image set inside the view, but it is not visible. Here is the source code.

Application Launcher

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    LOGGER.info("Start Application Frame");
    LOGGER.debug("Open splash screen");
    Parent splashScreen = showSplashScreen(primaryStage);

    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        ApplicationContext springContext = InitSpring.init();

        LOGGER.debug("Finish init spring - Start my application");
        springContext.getBean(ChangeViewService.class).changeView(splashScreen, springContext.getBean(MenuScreenController.class).getView());
    });

}

private Parent showSplashScreen(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = null;
    try {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/views/spalshscreen.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Fail to load splash screen", e);
        return null;
    }
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    // It comes later
    //scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    //primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setHeight(ApplicationSettings.SPLASH_SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    primaryStage.setWidth(ApplicationSettings.SPLASH_SCREEN_WIDTH);
    primaryStage.show();
    return root;
}
```

Splash Screen View

```
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="400" maxWidth="600" minHeight="400" minWidth="600" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="SplashScreenController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="splashImage" fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="600.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

SplashScreenController

```
import de.uni_bremen.roborally.gui.ApplicationSettings;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class SplashScreenController implements Initializable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SplashScreenController.class);

    @FXML private ImageView splashImage;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/game/splash.png"));
        LOGGER.debug("Is loaded: " + image.isError());
        splashImage.setImage(image);
        splashImage.setFitHeight(ApplicationSettings.SPLASH_SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        splashImage.setFitWidth(ApplicationSettings.SPLASH_SCREEN_WIDTH);
    }
}
```

The initialize method triggered correct, but the image do not show.

Comment: The threading is wrong here (in that it is not multi-threaded and runLater in the start method makes no sense).  Perhaps this [splash sample](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2305098) will give you an idea what to do.

Comment: @jewelsea - Thank you. It works.